# Titlebar with TabHost possible ?

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, title, titlebar

I have a `TabHost` with three tabs. I would like to add a title bar with icon if possible to match up visually with the rest of my app. I´m running `Android 2.3.3`.

In the rest of my App I am using the `Actionbar Sherlock`, so I have a nice `titlebar`. I would like to `"simulate"` this appearance for my `TabHost` as well. ( Of course I could  also use the Actionbar Sherlock and use Fragmnts etc. but that would be a lot of work for very little result!)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of android sample code for action bar compat..this sample code is available in the android-sdks/samples/android-14/ActionBarCompat..hope it helps

Comment: Compat Bar is pretty much the same as Actionbar Sherlock and only works using android 3.0 and above...